# call method with params in arguments through reflection c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection

Method return record from Database.

```
    public T Find(params object[] primaryKeys)
    {
        var dbSet = _sessionContext.Set<T>() as DbSet<T>;

        return dbSet != null ? dbSet.Find(primaryKeys) : null;
    }
```

I'm trying to call in through reflection

```
var methodCreateReadRepositoryEntity = 
     typeof(IRepositoryFactory)
    .GetMethod("CreateReadRepository")
    .MakeGenericMethod(entityMetadata.GetEntityType());

var entityReadRepository = 
     methodCreateReadRepositoryEntity
    .Invoke(_repositoryFactory, new object[] { _sessionMarketContext });

List<object> keys = new List<object>();

keys.Add(value);

var methodEntityGet = 
    entityReadRepository.GetType().GetMethod("Find", new Type[] { typeof(object[])});

var fromRepo = 
    methodEntityGet.Invoke(entityReadRepository, new object[]{new []{ keys.ToArray()[0]}});
```

value is Guid. And I have error

> The type of one of the primary key values did not match the type defined in the entity.
>   Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Comment: Why the `[0]` on `keys.ToArray()[0]`?

Comment: `.Find()` looks for a single entity

Comment: You might start by telling what you are trying to achieve. Perhaps knowing that would allow us to help, instead of trying to debug code that might not even match the goal you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Exist mechanism,which import data from xls file to db. But it only add  new record and i dont have ability to update  record in db thorgh import, because i have exeption that record is exist in table. I'm try to realize similar mechanism, whic will get existing record, modify it and save in db. I want that "var fromRepo" returns me entity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last line should be as follows. You need to be explicit with the array type, and there is no need to create a `List`.

```
var fromRepo = 
    methodEntityGet.Invoke(entityReadRepository, new object[]{new object []{value}});
```